# PHP: How to print value from mySQL database

Tags: php

I'm using php to count the times a link is clicked.

Now, I would like to display that number, but I'm not sure how.

The database is structured like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `count_clicks` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `url` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `clicks` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2;
```

The urls are stored in the database, and called with their id like this:

```
<a href="click.php?id=1">Click me</a>
```

Then it redirects to the url.

click.php:

```
// get url details based on ID
$sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $SETTINGS["data_table"] . " WHERE id='" . intval($_REQUEST["id"]) . "'";
$sql_result = mysql_query($sql, $connection) or die('request "Could not execute SQL query" ' . $sql);

// check if ID exists
if (mysql_num_rows($sql_result) > 0) {

    $item = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result);

    // increase clicks count by one
    $sql = "UPDATE " . $SETTINGS["data_table"] . " SET clicks=clicks+1 WHERE id='" . intval($_REQUEST["id"]) . "'";
    $sql_result = mysql_query($sql, $connection) or die('request "Could not execute SQL query" ' . $sql);

    header("Location: " . $item["url"]);

} else {
    echo "Item is missing.";
}
```

It works perfectly. But how do I create a php function that will allow me to echo the count for each link? I'm thinking like a function where the argument is the id - it will them return the count...

Comment: Can't you just `Select clicks from count_clicks` and echo the result? Or do I miss something?

Comment: Hello. First of all, you should use mysqli_* or PDO_* instead of mysql_* extension, since mysql is deprecated and not longer supported. To solve your problem take a look at the mysql `count` function (http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp). A bit old, but should still work. Also, you should look at what prepared statements are and use them to make your application more safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
//new mysql connection
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'username', 'password');

//select
$sql = "SELECT clicks FROM count_clicks";
foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
   echo "Klicks: ".$row['clicks']."<br />";
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks. But how can I display the count for each link - their id?

Comment: `SELECT clicks FROM count_clicks WHERE id = '1'` or you sort it by URL like this `SELECT clicks FROM count_clicks WHERE url = 'http://myURL'`

Comment: This help me forward, thanks. Can this be made into a function where I just pass the id as an argument, and then it returns the count for that id? Something like:

`function displayHits($id) {
    $sql = "SELECT clicks FROM count_clicks WHERE id = $id";
    foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
       echo "Klicks: ".$row['clicks'];
    }
}`

Comment: `$id = $_GET['id'];` above your select and then `SELECT clicks FROM count_clicks WHERE id = '".$id."'` now you can use **http://domain.com/index.php?id=1** for example

Comment: I ended up doing this:

`function displayHits($id) {
    include ("db.php");
    $sql = "SELECT clicks FROM count_clicks WHERE id = $id";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    if(mysql_num_rows($result)) {
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) or die(mysql_error());
        $clicks = $row['clicks'];
        echo $clicks;
    }
}` printing the result in my htmlwith `<?php displayHits(1) ?>` where the argument is the id. It works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

as i see , your are making a redirect when tou add a count, and you can compare first if is an add and make a redirect, and if is not get the counter value from database.
Expect it helps